# What are the mail service options for testing on local machine?

Tags: email, coldfusion

I want to setup some sort of mail service(a local SMTP server) on my local machine so that i can test user registrations and confirmations. I am using CFmail tag for sending out the mails.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to sensibly answer that without you telling us what OS you're running?? Also, is this not the sort of thing better googled that asking people on Stack Overflow? @VedantTerkar those are mail *clients* not mail servers. Windows comes with a basic SMTP server last time I checked. And I think SendMail is the usual *nix solution.

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you need to verify the content of the emails while developing? This can easily be done by viewing the undelivered emails from the ColdFusion Administrator. There is no need to have an SMTP server running locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using SMTP4Dev on Windows. It is a locally running SMTP Server which has a tray icon. All mails send to 127.0.0.1 will be listed and you can view them in outlook etc. No mails will be send to the actual "to"-address.

Memory footprint is low so I have it in auto start. It is just a single .exe file, no installation required.

Add the SMTP server 127.0.0.1 (port can be customized, default is 25) to the mailservers in ColdFusion Administrator.

Comment: Thank you @Maertsch I also found mailsnag and mailtrap

Answer (score 1):

I use mailcatcher quite a lot for local testing: 
[Setting Up Mailcatcher](https://serversforhackers.com/mailcatcher/)

Comment: Thanks @bvanvugt I will try use it for my Coldfusion app

Answer (score 0):

I Found what i was looking for so here is the link to MailSnag http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mailsnag Its a great plugin for eclipse for debugging application generated mails